# Cannot load --spec_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

I am running Rspec 3.0.0 and Ruby 1.9.3. 
I was going  through the test-first ruby tutorial: https://github.com/alexch/learn_ruby
When i go through the first excercise: 00_hello and run rake, I keep getting the following error:

```
c:\learn_ruby\00_hello>rake
(in c:/learn_ruby)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:
36:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

I tried suggestions such as putting the following in the gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0.beta' 
end 
bundle install
bundle exec 
rails generate rspec:install
```

that didn't help matters either, I also tried rspec --init, but I still keep getting the same error. I put require spec_helper in the hello_spec file too. Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec
$ rails generate rspec:install
```

Should be ran from the terminal, not put inside the gemfile.
Run `bundle` in the terminal then try your `rake` command again.

Comment: ok, so i put those commands in the terminal, it created the spec folder with spec_helper.rb in it. But, when I run rake, it still gives me the same error. What directory should I be running the rake file from?

Comment: nvm, i got it working, just had to make sure spec_helper was in the same folder as hello_spec. Thank you.